# Set max value for property Borderthickness

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this component `<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" x:Name="border"/>`
but I like to set the property `BorderThickess`  with a max value, for example `5`, in order of if I set `BorderThickess = 25`, automatically is setting in `5`, the max value.

Comment: Who/what controls the BorderThickness? Is it something that the user manipulates through a data binding on the ancestor of this ControlTemplate?  Because if so, you're better off putting the max value logic on the data binding to ensure that the value can never exceed 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your logic through Binding (for example you have BorderThickness property in your ViewModel and on 'set' you can accomplish that check for max 5). Other way you can do it is through converter https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
by throwing the BorderThickness property itself and checking either its greater than 5 or not and return appropriate value. But converter is probably not the best way to do this so I suggest you to use DataBinding for your property and change logic in 'set' method of that property.